# What is the kdb+ capital C type?

Tags: kdb, qpython

While trying to query a kdb instance I ran into some type conversion problems (using qPython). When getting the meta data of the table using `meta <tablename>` it returns the following:

```
c          | t f a
-----------| -----
time       | t
sym        | s   g
OrderID    | C
ClOrderID  | g
OrigClOrdID| g
SecurityID | s
Symbol     | s
Side       | c
OrderQty   | f
CumQty     | f
LeavesQty  | f
AvgPx      | f
Currency   | s
Commission | f
CommType   | c
CommValue  | f
Account    | s
MsgType    | s
OrdStatus  | s
OrderTime  | t
```

Now the `OrderID` column is the one causing me some trouble. I've looked at the kdb [docs](http://code.kx.com/wiki/Reference/Datatypes) I can find te `c` type which indicates the column type is a char, but I can't find anything on the (capital) `C` type.

I've tried treating it like a char, but that didn't work.

Any ideas on what this `C` means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capital types are nested lists - so the OrderID column in is a list, where each element of the list is a list of type character e.g

```
q)meta ([]OrderID:("hello";"there");charlist:"ht")
c       | t f a
--------| -----
OrderID | C
charlist| c
```

Answer (score 1):

Also while defining an empty table, it is **not** possible to define the column type as a `char` list.

```
q)t:([] oid:();price:`float$();side:`char$() )
q)meta t
c    | t f a
-----| -----
oid  |          //type undefined 
price| f
side | c

q)meta t upsert `oid`price`side!("123";100.01;"B")
c    | t f a
-----| -----
oid  | C
price| f
side | c
```

Care must be taken while inserting the first record in this case, otherwise, it might take some unintentional structure.
Example if the `oid` is inserted as a symbol rather than `char` list.

```
q)show meta t upsert `oid`price`side!(`$"123";100.01;"B")
c    | t f a
-----| -----
oid  | s
price| f
side | c
```